# R language parameters for `listings` package

Tags: listings, r, parameters

I tried all answers posted here or on other pages, but nothing worked. I need to set the parameters for `listings` package to simulate R code, so:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
language=R,
% parameters here
{
```

All the suggested questions/answers gave me some strange-looking code. Maybe R has different code coloring for different versions? I have R studio, it's a relatively new R environment.

Comment: if nothing satisfactory exists you can write your own language bindings, it's not particularly difficult. Start with the keywords and comment characters, and go on from there.

Comment: Have you tried [SweaveListingUtils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SweaveListingUtils/index.html) or [knitr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html)?

Comment: @hpesoj626 I haven't tried them. How do I actually use those packages? Do they enable me to include R files into my document? Or they enable me to type R-like code in my document?

Comment: Personally, I use the `knitr` package by [Yihui](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9128/yihui), who is also a member of this site. Yihui has some demo files in `knitr`'s official site: http://yihui.name/knitr/. What you do is you write your LaTeX file as you usually do but save it as a `.Rnw` file instead of `.tex`. Of course you should install `knitr` in R first using `install.packages`. You then load it via `library(knitr)` and knit your document by running `knit("yourfile.Rnw")` in your R console. I usually use `knitr` with [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example to get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=R,literate={<-}{{$\gets$}}1}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  a <- c(1,2,3)
  b <- data.frame(this=a,that=c(3,4,5))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The "literate" part gives you nicer assignment arrows, which is useful if you use "<-" for assignment, and there is a great deal more customisation that you can do.  For full details you should read the [fine manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) on CTAN.

Comment: that's nice, thank you, but could you maybe suggest more parameters? for a complete syntax? :) if i knew how to create them, I would've done so on my own :P

Comment: @Vidak Does [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/113688.html) help?